# Using Google Maps with a Windows 8 C#/XAML app

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps, xaml, windows-8

I just installed the Windows 8 RTM/64 bit Professional version on a separate partition, and am learning the details of how to make Win 8 apps. I'd like to reuse some code from an earlier webapp I wrote, using asp.net and MVC3. Is there a way to use the Google Maps API with a C#/xaml app? I guess it'd be a lot easier for me, less having to reinvent the wheel and just pasting code, but I'm sorta at a loss how I'd do it.

The code behind for the asp.net app was written in C#, and it parses XML. On the other hand, could I do this with a JS/HTML5 app? Is there someway I can use server side code in a Win 8 app? I'm not sure if that question even makes sense.

Thanks,

Amanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript api would have to be implemented in an HTML5 Win 8 App. However, you could use the static map API. You can certainly use server side code in your Win 8 apps. The main difference is that you need to make Asynchronous calls when calling services. The System.Net.HTTP class can help you with this. The best method to parse XML is with LINQ.